# Prosody refuse to connect to MySQL database after update to Debian Buster

Tags: lua, debian, mysql-connector, debian-buster, prosody-im

I updated my server to Debian Buster and now Prosody 0.11.2-1 refuses to connect to the MySQL database. It looks like Prosody starts fine, but no user is able to login to their account. If I look at the debug log I see this:

```
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql debug   Connecting to [MySQL] prosody...
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql debug   Database connection was closed. Will reconnect and retry.
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql debug   Retrying SQL transaction [function(mod_storage_sql.lua:137)]
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql debug   Connecting to [MySQL] prosody...
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql debug   SQL transaction retry failed
Nov 30 22:09:15 sql error   Error in SQL transaction: /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/DBI.lua:53: Cannot load driver MySQL. Available drivers are: SQLite3
```

Lua Version is 5.2.4 and both "lua-dbi-mysql/stable,now 0.7.1-2 amd64" and "lua-sql-mysql/stable,now 2.3.4-1+b1 amd64" are installed.

Comment: The error message say that you don't have mysql driver installed. Install the required driver.

Comment: That's also how I understand it but I don't know what extra package I should install. Shouldn't  "lua-dbi-mysql/stable,now 0.7.1-2 amd64" and "lua-sql-mysql/stable,now 2.3.4-1+b1 amd64" contain all the necessary drivers?

Comment: The strange thing, as soon as I install "lua-dbi-postgresql", the last statement in the log changes to "Available drivers are: SQLite3,PostgreSQL", but "lua-dbi-mysql" seems to be not enough to enable mysql support.